# How to abort waiting for sys.stdin in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, stdin, sys

I'm running a script with two threads, a thread reading from a subprocess, and the main thread.

inside the main thread, I'm reading from `stdin`, like so:

```
for line in sys.stdin:

    if proc.poll() != None:
        break

    proc.stdin.write(line)
    proc.stdin.flush()

    <other things happen here>
```

*(`proc` is the external subprocess)*

Now, this works well, until I want to close my program. When the process in the other thread exits, I want the whole program to stop, but the main thread still waits for something to be entered into `stdin`. How can I abort that?

Basically, I want `stdin` to be signaled an `EOF`, but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would swap the threads around. Read from the subprocess in the main thread, and do the blocking `sys.stdin` stuff in the other thread. That way you can pass `daemon=True` to `threading.Thread` which makes the thread exit when the main thread exits.